# How can I fix "Symbol not found: _NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown" when running tests using Travis that work locally?

Tags: objective-c, macos, travis-ci, xctool

The command `xctool -workspace Foo.xcworkspace -scheme Foo -sdk macosx -configuration Debug test -test-sdk macosx` works locally and all of the tests pass.

Using Travis I get the following error:

```
Failed to query the list of test cases in the test bundle: dlopen(/Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Foo-bvxkmfrwzzvtxgaeoosknyzjovjc/Build/Products/Debug/OS X Tests.xctest/Contents/MacOS/OS X Tests, 2): Symbol not found: _NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown
  Referenced from: /Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Foo-bvxkmfrwzzvtxgaeoosknyzjovjc/Build/Products/Debug/OS X Tests.xctest/Contents/MacOS/OS X Tests
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
 in /Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Foo-bvxkmfrwzzvtxgaeoosknyzjovjc/Build/Products/Debug/OS X Tests.xctest/Contents/MacOS/OS X Tests
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
** TEST FAILED: 0 passed, 0 failed, 0 errored, 0 total ** (21121 ms)
The command "xctool -workspace Foo.xcworkspace -scheme Foo -sdk macosx -configuration Debug test -test-sdk macosx" exited with 1.
```

My `.travis.yml` file is as follows:

```
language: objective-c
before_install:
  - gem install cocoapods --no-ri --no-rdoc --no-document --quiet
  - brew update
  - brew uninstall xctool
  - brew install xctool
script:
  - xctool -workspace Foo.xcworkspace -scheme Foo -sdk macosx -configuration Debug test -test-sdk macosx
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix this?

Comment: Is the machine osx 10.9? NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown is available on 10.9+ only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Travis does not currently support Mavericks which is the root cause of the problem.

Support for 10.9 is being tracked in [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1851).